# InvalidOprerationException while trying to insert data into databse using entityframework MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There are 2 tables in my database,
1. Employee, The model is below.

```
public class Employees
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual IList<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

I have another table named Address. The model is as below.

```
public class Address
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
}
```

An employee can have multiple address. I am dynamically adding controls for adding address. I am using Entityframe work for all the operations like creating DB, Updating etc.

The code I use for adding the data to database is as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(string command,[Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,DepartmentId,Designation,DateOfBirth")] Employees employees, [Bind(Include = "Id,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,State,PinCode")] List<Address> address)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in address)
                {
                    db.Address.Add(item);
                }
                db.Employees.Add(employees);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employees);
    }
```

When I insert data, the data is getting inserted in the database but I am getting the following exception.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Unable to set field/property Address on entity type GridSample.Models.Employees. See InnerException for details.

The Innerexception :

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'GridSample.Models.Address' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[GridSample.Models.Address]'."}

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use `ForeignKeyAttribute` on a property in the "one" class in one-to-many relation. It should be used on a property in the "many" class to specify the key of the "one" class instance. So, in your case, you should modify your entity classes to reflect the relationship.

```
public class Employees
{
    //...

    [InverseProperty("Employee")]
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    //...

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId"), InverseProperty("Addresses")]
    public virtual Employees Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Here the `ForeignKeyAttribute` is used to decorate the navigation property and specify the key property. Otherwise, you can decorate the key property and specify the navigation property, like so:

```
public class Address
{
    //...

    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Addresses")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

The reason you're not getting any addresses is because you're adding employee and addresses to the database independently, i.e. without indicating the relation between them. There are several ways to do that, and I think the simplest is to make use of the navigation properties:

Either I: Add the addresses to the employee's address collection rather than directly to a dbset:

```
foreach (var item in address)
{
    employees.Addresses.Add(item);
}
db.Employees.Add(employees);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or II: For each address specify the employee to whom it belongs:

```
foreach (var item in address)
{
    item.Employee = employees;
    db.Address.Add(item);
}
db.Employees.Add(employees);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This Didn't work. I am not getting values in the Address now.

Comment: For me the address is coming as null.